# insert each month to its own column (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, dax

I need to compare months in power bi. "How many incidents happened in may versus june". I know how to group up incidents to places but i dont know how to split incidents into months.

Sourcedata: two tables, Place and Incidents

[image]

Idea is to query this result directly from database using postreSQL. Then i can pick the months which i want to compare in power bi. But i do not know how to split months into columns. Each month creates a new column. Any suggestions?

Data contains over 100 places, over 10 000 incidents and over 20 months.

Comment: not sure I understand... you want to create the "result" in a database and then import it to Power BI?

Comment: my power bi is connected to database which contains those two tables. So i want to do a query in power bi query editor which gives me the "result" result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the crosstab function from the tablefunc extension, check e.g. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/571215

Full documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html